# Making a ball fall through a net (childnode) and make a swish movement? (PhysicsBody/ARKit)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

Wondering how make to a basketball fall through a net and make a swish movement? There's already a gravity force on the ball but it won't completely fall through the net because of the shape. I need to somehow make the net flexible to allow the ball (sphere) to pass through when entered from the top of the rim. The ball only stops 1/3 of the way down. I'm experimenting with the iOS ARKit (SceneKit) on Xcode. Thank you!

[image: Screenshot Photo]

1. Code for ball.

   ```
   let ball = SCNSphere(radius: 0.15)

   let material = SCNMaterial()
   material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "basketballSkin.png")
   ball.materials = [material]

   let ballNode = SCNNode(geometry: ball)
   ballNode.position = cameraPosition

   let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: ballNode, options: nil)
   let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physicsShape)

   ballNode.physicsBody = physicsBody

   let forceVector:Float = 6
   ballNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(x: cameraOrientation.x * forceVector,y: cameraOrientation.y * forceVector ,z: cameraOrientation.z * forceVector), asImpulse: true)

   sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ballNode)
   ```

---

2. Code for the net, apart of the backboard node.

   ```
   func addBackboard(){
   guard let backboardScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/hoop.scn") else{
       return
   }
       guard let backboardNode = backboardScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "backboard", recursively: false) else{
           return
   }

       backboardNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 0.5,z: -3)

       let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node : backboardNode, options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron])
       let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: physicsShape)

       backboardNode.physicsBody = physicsBody

       sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(backboardNode)
       currentNode = backboardNode
   ```

---

-Luther

Comment: thanks Luther, what was finally your implementation of the net? I'm a bit curious :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions worth to try. A really cool one would be creating the net with a [Particle System](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnparticlesystem), this is instead of the classical net you can place something more creative, sophisticated and vivid, ex. the net can be moving due to the wind and then altered by the hit of the ball

Other solution could be creating a sequence of nodes representing the different alterations suffered by the net while the ball is passing trough, the sequence should start when the ball touches some transparent node inside the net.

Good look, such an nice challenge